# Handling Runtime errors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to handle runtime errors in Javascript. But I'm faced with a problem. When I used to window.onerror function I can get unexception errors. But I'm defining an undefined function inside any defined function. I can't see any exception. Where I am doing a mistake ?

Here is my code that I used;

```
function errorHandler(message, url, line, column, error) {
debugger    
var message = [
'Message: ' + message,
'\nURL: ' + url,
'\nLine: ' + line,
'\nColumn: ' + column,
];
```

}
window.onerror = errorHandler;

index.html code;

```
function exceptionTest() {
        test();
    }
```

exceptionTest() function is defined in my code. But test function is undefined. I want to get an error about that undefined function. How can I do that ? It is showing only browser's console window.
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: The exception object in try catch block has those properties which you've listed as parameters in "errorHandler" function. So you have two options. Either in catch block pass the exception object and retrieve its information or in the catch block break the exception object and call the "errorHandler" function.

Comment: You can check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: Can I get all runtime errors without using try catch blocks ? Do I need to add try catch in every function ?

Comment: When I used to try catch blocks. window.onerror function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use try catch blocks to catch these errors:

```
try{
    test();
} catch(error){
   console.log("Following error happened:", error);
}
```

Comment: In Fact, I want to use a global event handler instead of try catch blocks. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried below use case where **onerror** is taken from [this MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="Test1();">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Test1() {
            Test2();
        }

        window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
            var string = msg.toLowerCase();
            var substring = "script error";
            if (string.indexOf(substring) > -1) {
                alert('Script Error: See Browser Console for Detail');
            } else {
                var message = [
                    'Message: ' + msg,
                    'URL: ' + url,
                    'Line: ' + lineNo,
                    'Column: ' + columnNo,
                    'Error object: ' + JSON.stringify(error)
                ].join(' - ');

                //uncomment below line to see the message in console.
                //console.log(message); 
                alert(message);
            }

            return false;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And it shows correct message with the location of the error with line number and column number.

The error information when logged to console is as below:

```
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
HTMLPage1.html
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
HTMLPage1.html
SCRIPT5009: 'Test2' is undefined
HTMLPage1.html (12,13)
Message: 'Test2' is undefined - URL: file:Desktop/HTMLPage1.html - Line: 12 - Column: 13 - Error object: undefined
HTMLPage1.html (29,17)
```

Comment: When I used to try catch block inside Test1 function. window.onerror doesn't catch any error. This is as it should be, right ?

Comment: If I add a new undefined function next to the Test2() function. The error handler return only one undefined function error. Can not find the other undefined function. Is it possible to catch other exceptions ? Thank you

Comment: @MLE Whenever there is an exception or error, JavaScript will create an exception object which will have many properties. Including the ones mentioned above there is one more important property called Stack. This Stack property, which is string, is broken in various parameters when called through "window.onerror". Whenever you use "try...catch" block, JavaScript won't decipher the stack property, it will be your responsibility to do so.

Comment: @MLE One shortest way is to throw exception object again so that it will be caught by window.onerror function. For your first query, what do you mean by it doesn't catch any error? The functional behavior of "catch" block in any language is to catch the exception. Please provide the code that isn't catching any error inside "try...catch" block.

Comment: @MLE, JavaScript is runtime language. Meaning that if you add another undefined after Test2(), it won't recognize it during compile. And as with any other language, once it encounters the exception, it will stop the execution of code till a "catch" block is found or it will return from the first function in stack chain. It won't execute any code that is written after error line. So First it will show issue about "Test2" which you'll have to rectify first and then second mistake and so forth. I hope all of your doubts are cleared.